# Integrate Facebook 'Page' Status Into Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need your help and advice yet again!

I'm trying to do a website as part of a group project at uni, developing for a friend's business, and I'm ready to pull my hair out!

I'm completely stuck at embedding status updates on the website. I have got the RSS feed url and have tried several website such as http://www.rssinclude.com to embed it in a usable format.

The feed does not validate as well-formed RSS here: 
http://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffeeds%2Fpage.php%3Fid%3D116381405151339%26format%3Drss20

You can see an example of the feed embedded here:
http://theartificialasylum.com/Joe_Website/blog.html

I've read numerous different ways of fetching details, using Facebook API - which seems to have disappeared? and other SDK's.

I want to be able to style the status update stuff when I embed it on the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2: From your further descriptions, I think the Like box should be enough and its much easier to use - make sure "show Stream" is checked on (You can turn off show Faces & header). http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

---

The Facebook API is still around and is how you should interact with Facebook.

The Facebook Live Stream plugin does exactly what you seem to require, and this page even gives you the code to include in your page:
[Facebook Live Stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/)

Edit: Don't forget you will need to register your website to get an AppID first: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: I'll look into that now. Thanks for your speedy advice..!

Comment: @JohnDoe: Don't forget you will need to register your website to get an AppID first: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: Thanks FluffyK, was just bouncing between websites trying to figure out how to get one. I had the same problem when using Google maps API for Android, difficult to find a straight answer anywhere!

Comment: It might be me being thick headed. But this is way complex for what I want to do, I have created an app on FB, getting into defining actions and aggregations. 

All I need is for Status updates from an individual page to show up on the website being developed.

The Website is for Lucky Edge Decks, there is a Lucky Edge Decks Facebook page and I want their status updates to appear in the blog area of the website.

I really cant work out how thats done using a FB app. =|

Comment: Is Tumblr a better option for this kind of thing?

Comment: You don't need to create a Facebook App, all you need is the App ID so your external website is authorised to access your Status updates - otherwise anyone could post your status updates on their sites. It doesn't matter if you are using the Facebook Live Stream or any other way of accessing it, you need the App ID!

Comment: How can I register my website without creating an app? It's the only way I can see.. Do I just create an app so I can steal its appId?

Comment: Pretty much!
But from what you have just said, I think the LIKE box should be enough for you: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ Just make sure Show Stream is checked and you can turn off show Faces

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7922/discussion-between-johndoe-and-fluffykitten)